# Password protect a CSV file

Tags: csv, php-5.3

I am using a csv file to authenticate user login. Is it possible to password protect the CSV file? I do not want anybody to be able to download the csv file through url. I googled and I found out that it is not possible to password protect a csv file. Is there any other way I can password protect the file?

Comment: Please, please, just don't do this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the short answer is no: CSV is a plain text format, it's not Excel.

the long answer is: you should never put security relevant information into a folder which is accessible via the webserver. move the file into a folder you can access from PHP but which is outside of your document root in Apache

Comment: definitely do so, and make sure you use salted hashes

Answer (score 1):

Compress it in a ZIP file using encryption. You'll have to decompress/unencrypt it each time you want to read from it, however.

See [Powerarchiver](http://www.powerarchiver.com/), [winrar](http://www.rarlab.com/), or other compression utilities for more information.

Comment: could you please show me how will I encrypt/unencrypt using code in php?

Comment: Instead of zipping it I’d just encrypt it. Checking the php doc the mcrypt_encrypt function would be one. http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php (which probably requires mcrypt as a dependency)

Comment: just make sure you can't download it. that makes much more sense than encrypting it and leave it in public place

Comment: @developer: Kissaki is right, simply encrypting it will be likely better. Moreover, according to http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php, there doesn't seem to be an encrypt/decrypt built into the PHP zip library.

Answer (score 1):

If using Apache, use a .htaccess file to deny access to that file. Better still, store the file somewhere above the webroot. For example, if your webserver is located at `/home/username/htdocs/`, you could store the file at `/home/username/data/logins.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about someone downloading the file, put it someplace that isn't downloadable.  Your webserver will only return files from a specific set of directories.  If your CSV file is not in one of them, nobody will be able to download it.