# File with no password when I use SaveAs

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to use the SaveAs to save a new document with a Password, I used the value of one cell to assign the password. All the code works fine the error happens when the file is save and I open it, there´s no password protecting the file. If somebody could help me to find the error in the code I'll be thankfull:

```
Bloqueo = Range("E2").Value
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="Cortesías" & NombreCine & ".csv", _
       FileFormat:=xlCSV, Password:=Bloqueo, _
       WriteResPassword:=Bloqueo, AddToMru:=True
```

Comment: [CSV files don't have a password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738874/password-protect-a-csv-file).

Comment: If you want password protection you'll need to save in Excel format, or put the file in a password-protected zip archive.

Comment: @TimWilliams could you help me with the correct code to save it in a password-protected zip archive,I have been looking the way but a I can not find it.

Comment: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s7/win003.htm